# Group select data from table with Same lenght

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

my price table is like this:

[image]

i want to get query from price of two city in the same date from one product for comparing price.
but in some time may be a city have more price on specific date, and the query of two city is not same length for comparing.

[image]

How to restrict two city price to just have get price if that product in two city is exists in specific time?
like This:

[image]

Comment: Totally not clear what to do then... do you want a list of product ids that exist in two more cities at the same time?

Comment: 1394 was quite a long time ago.In fact it predates the Gregorian calendar by approximately 200 years! Also, at least some RDBMSs have a concept of data types. I would suggest that you familiarise yourself with them before proceeding. If these dates are in fact relating to the Persian/Iranian calendar then you would be well advised to store the Gregorian date and do the conversion in your application level code.

Comment: @Strawberry yea i use the date field for Persian/jalali calendar that table just for test and i save  Gregorian calendar  in end of work...

Comment: Well, for our benefit, maybe work with the Gregorian calendar for the time being - and sort out your data types. Use string types for string data, and numeric types for numeric data.

Comment: @Hogan sorry for bad telling my purpose... i want to compare price of one product in two city

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a list of product codes and dates that have more than one entry.

```
select product_code, date_price
from price_table
group by product_code, date_price
having count(*) > 1
```

---

**edit:**

You would probably use the above query in the following way --

```
select *
from price_table as p
join (select product_code, date_price
      from price_table
      group by product_code, date_price
      having count(*) > 1
) as price_with_more_than_one on price_with_more_than_one.procuct_code = p.prouct_code 
                             and price_with_more_than_one.date_price = p.date_price
```

**note**

> This may or may not be what you want to do, since you never said what you want to do with ALL the product_codes which have more than one item for a given date I can't say if this is exactly what you want.  But, I'm guessing this query will at least show you some results which can then drive your next question.

Comment: this query just get one price, i want get all price of one product in same time at two city...

Comment: @javaddroid please see my above edit.  I understand exactly what you are asking so far.  It is what you are not telling me I don't understand.

Comment: I apologize hogan for bad question. i have some product and some city. in price table i added price of one product in specific date at specific city. i want to get all price from one product in two specific city for comparing the price. how can do that?

Comment: @javadroid -- if my edit does not help then you should give example data, example input (parameters) and expected result in your question and I will be able to help you.

Comment: yea.. that work... last question: how to set two city_code for get price? i just need two specific city_code price.

Comment: @javaddroid - I've no idea what you mean.  Give me inputs and expected results